# Change End-Of-Scroll Sound in Ubuntu 18

Tags: 18.04, sound, emacs

This is probably trivial to do, but I am wondering how one can change the end-of-scroll sound made by Ubuntu 18. This sound is also heard when I use some unknown key-chords in Emacs. I am not sure whether the one I currently hear is native or not because I have a theme and some tweaks installed. However, it is pretty obnoxious. Any help on how I can tweak it would be great.